# Converting object to array | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

A list is coming from the backend.

response;

```
activePoliciesMap:
 OTHER: Array(3)
   0: {policyNumber: '1184140022', …}
   1: {policyNumber: '1272731122', …}
   2: {policyNumber: '100091622', …}
 length: 3
 PET: Array(1)
  0: {policyNumber: '1272741022', …}
   length: 1
 RESIDENCE: Array(2)
  0: {policyNumber: '1277976920', …}
  1: {policyNumber: '1064318822', …}
 length: 2
 TRAVEL: Array(1)
  0: {policyNumber: '1271732822', …}
 length: 1
```

I want to print all of them, regardless of the type of product.

I tried to convert the values inside the object to array. But I was not successful.

```
const activePolicyList = [];

useEffect(() => {
  if (props.activePolicy !== undefined) {
    Object.values(props.activePolicy).map((policyType) => {
      Object.values(policyType).map((policyList) => {
        policyList.map((policy) => {
          if (activePolicyList.length === 0) {
            activePolicyList.push({
              policy
            });
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
  console.log(activePolicyList);
}, []);
```

After running this code I am only able to display a single element.

I can view;

```
0:
 policy:
  policyNumber: "1277976920"
```

How can I collect all the elements in a single list?

Comment: please add data in text form.

Comment: Can you please also add an example of what your expected output is for the data you've shown?

Comment: it looks like just `Object.values(data.activePoliciesMap).flat()`

Comment: @pilchard is right.

Comment: checking `if (activePolicyList.length === 0)` doesn't seem logical either :)

Comment: @Nsevens I tried but the array is empty.

Comment: Please add your data as a valid JS object, so that we can copy it into code to test, and not as the console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `props.activePolicy` is the object `{ activePoliciesMap: {...} }`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let activePolicyList = [];

  if (props.activePolicy !== undefined) {
    Object.values(props.activePolicy.activePoliciesMap).forEach((policies) => {
      activePolicyList = activePolicyList.concat(policies);
    });
  }

  console.log(activePolicyList);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Object.entries` and `flatMap` for that

```js
const data = {
activePoliciesMap: {
 OTHER: [ 
    {policyNumber: '1184140022'},
    {policyNumber: '1272731122'},
    {policyNumber: '100091622'}
 ],
 PET:[ 
   {policyNumber: '1272741022'}
   ],
 RESIDENCE: [
 {policyNumber: '1277976920'},
  {policyNumber: '1064318822'}
],
 TRAVEL:[
 {policyNumber: '1271732822'}
 ]}
 }
 
const active = Object.entries(data.activePoliciesMap).flatMap(([_, p]) => p)
 
 console.log(active)
```

I suggest you to store those data into a state like this

```
const [active, setActive] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
   if(!data.activePoliciesMap) return;

   setActive(Object.entries(data.activePoliciesMap).flatMap(([_, p]) => p))
}, [data])
```

Comment: Why `entries`? It just leads to an unneeded map (and destructuring). Just `Object.values(data.activePoliciesMap).flat();`